# Javascript async await with canvas

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, canvas, async-await

I'm creating a canvas with mutiple images, but they need to be added in a certain order, for example sky first, the clouds, moutains, hills, grass, road, then car.

When I add the images they load at different times so can't get the order right.  My plan was to use a async function so that they wait for each image to finish.  But it's not working.  Code below.

```
function addImageProcess(src){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let img = new Image()
    img.onload = () => resolve(img)
    img.onerror = reject
    img.src = src
  })
}

addImageProcess('sky.png').then(img => { canvas2.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0) });
addImageProcess('clouds.png').then(img => { canvas2.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0) });
addImageProcess('moutains.png').then(img => { canvas2.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0) });
addImageProcess('hills.png').then(img => { canvas2.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0) });
addImageProcess('grass.png').then(img => { canvas2.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0) });
addImageProcess('road.png').then(img => { canvas2.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0) });
addImageProcess('car.png').then(img => { canvas2.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0) });
```

Have been pulling my hair out for hours trying to get this to work, hopefully someone can help!

Comment: Try using `promise.all` so you can only start drawing when all images have loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Promise.all`:

```
Promise.all(
    [
        'sky.png', 'clouds.png', 'mountains.png', 'hills.png', 'grass.png', 'road.png', 'car.png'
    ].map(
        addImageProcess
    )
).then(
    (allImages)=>allImages.map(
        img=>canvas2.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0)
    )
)
```

`Promise.all` can be used to wait for all promises to finish before moving on to the next phase.

If you want to do something different with each image you can do something like this:

```
Promise.all(
    [
        'sky.png', 'clouds.png', 'mountains.png', 'hills.png', 'grass.png', 'road.png', 'car.png'
    ].map(
        addImageProcess
    )
).then(
    ([sky, clouds, mountains, hills, grass, road, car])=>{
         const context = canvas2.getContext('2d');
         
         context.drawImage(clounds, 5, 2);
         context.drawImage(hills, 20, 50);
    }
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works great!  Also as added bonus, with your code you don't see the images loading one by one, it all appears at once, so looks like one image.

Comment: would you know of a simple way of passing the x,y, coordinates too?  some of the images are not at 0,0?

Comment: Thanks again, the updated example is superb, well both examples really.  You're a star.